# Exporting time lapse with AVAssetExportSession results in black video

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, photosframework

I need to be able to merge videos taken with the time lapse function in the Camera app on iOS and export as a single video.

However, even if I try to export a single, unchanged time lapse video to the Photo Library, it saves as a completely black video (with the correct duration). Here is the sample code I wrote to just export a single, unchanged video (most of which is adapted from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial):

```
@IBAction func saveVideo(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // 1 - Early exit if there's no video file selected

    guard let videoAsset = self.avAsset else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Failed to load video asset.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    // 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
    print("Preparing AVMutableComposition...")
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    // 3 - Video track
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)


    do {
        if let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first {
            try videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        if let audioAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first {
            let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
            try audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: audioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        self.presentAlert(title: "Export Error", message: "Unable to complete export due to the following error: \(error). Please try again.", block: nil)
        print("error: \(error)")
    }

    // 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)

    // 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
    let videoLayerInstruction: AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack!)
    let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
    var assetOrientation: UIImageOrientation = .up
    var isPortrait = false
    let t = videoAssetTrack!.preferredTransform
    if t.a == 0 && t.b == 1.0 && t.c == -1.0 && t.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
    } else if t.a == 0 && t.b == -1.0 && t.c == 1.0 && t.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
    } else if t.a == 1.0 && t.b == 0 && t.c == 0 && t.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
    } else if t.a == -1.0 && t.b == 0 && t.c == 0 && t.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
    }

    videoLayerInstruction.setTransform(videoAssetTrack!.preferredTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)
    videoLayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: videoAsset.duration)

    // 3.3 - Add instructions
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [videoLayerInstruction]

    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    var naturalSize: CGSize
    if isPortrait {
        naturalSize = CGSize(width: videoAssetTrack!.naturalSize.height, height: videoAssetTrack!.naturalSize.width)
    } else {
        naturalSize = videoAssetTrack!.naturalSize
    }

    mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: naturalSize.width, height: naturalSize.height)

    // set up file destination
    let tempName = "temp-thread.mov"
    let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(tempName))
    do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempURL.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempURL)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error removing temp file.")
    }
    // create final video using export session
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
    exportSession.outputURL = tempURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.videoComposition = mainComposition
    print("Exporting video...")
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch exportSession.status {
            // Success
            case .completed:
                print("Saving to Photos Library...")
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exportSession.outputURL!)
                }) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("Added video to library - success: \(success), error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                    } else {
                        print("Added video to library - success: \(success), error: \(String(describing: error!.localizedDescription))")
                    }

                    let _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempURL)
                }
                print("Export session completed")
            // Status other than success
            case .cancelled, .exporting, .failed, .unknown, .waiting:
                print("Export status: \(exportSession.status.rawValue)")
                print("Reason: \(String(describing: exportSession.error))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why would the resulting video show up completely black? I can't seem to find much documentation on Apple's time lapse videos, so I'm not sure why they might be different than a regular video file. They seem to have a frame rate of 30fps and if I inspect one on my Mac, it's just a regular QuickTime movie file without an audio channel. Any ideas? Exporting any other video with this code (even ones without audio) works flawlessly.

Comment: I can't comment on above code but please try this one https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder

Answer (score 0):

The problem code is:

```swift
videoLayerInstruction.setTransform(videoAssetTrack!.preferredTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)
```

This transformation is eligible to "up" (default) orientation only and it makes a video completely black for the other orientations. You should make a correct transformation for each orientation e.g.:

```swift
var transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
// Right
if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
    isPortrait = true
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.tx, y: -videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.ty)
    transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(rotate)
}
// Left
else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
    isPortrait = true
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x:  -videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.tx, y: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.ty)
    transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(rotate)
}
// Up
else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
    transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
}
// Down
else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.tx, y: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height - videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.ty)
    transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(rotate)
}

videoLayerInstruction.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
```

Comment: `videoAssetTrack!.preferredTransform` works perfectly for all other types of video in every orientation. Why doesn't it work for time-lapse?

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a solution which works for all video types, while it doesn't feel right to apply a different set of transformations for time-lapse only.

Comment: @AttilaH It should work for all videos. `preferredTransform` contains the media orientation information (sometimes it equals `CGAffineTransform.identity` no transformations at all - maybe it’s your case). All movies recorded using the default iPhone camera app have a video frame set to landscape and the iPhone saves the media in landscape mode but for instance AVPlayer applies this info with transformations and shows the video correctly. So you should analyse an orientation of a video and apply correct transformation while merging e.g.: to rotate and fit landscape to portrait etc.

Comment: @AttilaH Simply say you should transform a source non-default `preferredTransform` (orientation) to default one - `CGAffineTransform.identity` because `AVAssetExportSession` exports a video with default transform.

Comment: I’ve tried applying ‘preferredTransform’ in all 8 orientation cases and it works flawlessly (it only equals to identity in one case). What I wonder is in what aspect a time-lapse video is different?